# Laravel multiple table relation using eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following table structure and trying to use eloquent relationships between bellow tables but not able to understand how to apply.

```php
$user = User::find('4')->load(['usersBusinessWeb']);
return View::make('admin.dashboard')->with('user', $user);
```

based on above code I am getting user & tbl_users_business details but now I want to fetch tbl_master_business_types, tbl_users_business_document on business_id column so can you please guide us.

## Tables:

```php
users
-----
user_id | business_id (p.k. of tbl_users_business) | first_name | last_name | email
4       | 1                                        | Samuel     | Petersen  | samuel_petersen@mailinator.com

------------------
tbl_users_business
------------------
business_id | user_id (p.k. of users) | business_type_id (p.k. of tbl_master_business_types) | business_name
1           | 4                       | 3                                                    | Charde Terry

-------------------------
tbl_master_business_types
-------------------------
business_type_id | business_type_name | description
1                | Movie              | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2                | Hotel              | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3                | Restaurant         | xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

---------------------------
tbl_users_business_document
---------------------------
business_document_id | business_id (p.k. of tbl_users_business) | doc_path
1                    | 1                                        | sample1.pdf
2                    | 1                                        | sample1.pdf
```

## Models:

```php
User Model
----------
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    use HasApiTokens;

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'business_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
    ];

    public function usersBusinessWeb()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\UsersBusiness', 'business_id');
    }
}

-------------------
UsersBusiness Model
-------------------
class UsersBusiness extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'business_id';

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_users_business';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'business_type_id', 'business_name'
    ];
}

-------------------------
MasterBusinessTypes Model
-------------------------
class MasterBusinessTypes extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'business_type_id';

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_master_business_types';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'business_type_name', 'description'
    ];
}

---------------------------
UsersBusinessDocument Model
---------------------------
class UsersBusinessDocument extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'business_document_id';

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'tbl_users_business_document';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'business_id', 'doc_path', 'doc_type'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need business_id on users table.

Relations:

> User hasMany() or hasOne() UserBusiness, 
>    UserBusiness belongTo() MasterBusinessTypes,
>    UserBusiness hasMany() UsersBusinessDocument

```
    $business = $user->business->find($id);

    $business->businessType;
    business->docs;
```